# I cannot create actual PDFs with domPDF

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, helper, dompdf

**I can't get domPDF to work.**

I have done as this article: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PDF-generation-using-dompdf - with one exception: I loaded it from Google (https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/detail?name=dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.zip&can=2&q=) instead because there are missing files in the GitHub (for some reason)

I tried both to put helpers in the `system/helpers` and `application/helpers` - but still having the same issue.

I have this in my controller:

```
    $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));

    //I know this is correct because $html returns content of view
    $html = $this->load->view('actual viewfile', $content_data, TRUE); 

    //Try to create a pdf
    pdf_create($html, '/pdf/test');               //It seems it's trying to create a pdf

    //But...
    echo 'FINAL'; //...it never reaches this line
    exit;
```

I have created a folder called `pdf` in my `www` - root (not application root)

I don't know it makes a difference but this is how my htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've also tried to change to

```
define("DOMPDF_AUTOLOAD_PREPEND", true) in dompdf_config.custom.inc.php.
```

It seems it's trying to create the PDF but nothing seems to be created (and it never reaches the line echoing final. What could be wrong?

**UPDATE**
After some searching I get this in my apache error logs:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 79 bytes) in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\mellomgarden2\application\helpers\dompdf\include\style.cls.php on line 718
```

Comment: That's roughly 128MB memory available to PHP. It could be that between dompdf and CI you don't have enough memory available. This is something you may have to set in your php.ini (depending on your hosting situation). The memory requirements of dompdf depend greatly on the content and structure of your PDF. Seeing a sample document might help determine why you're having issues.

Comment: Note that [dompdf 0.6.0 final is available](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.1), so you might want to upgrade. If you're using PHP 5.4 or greater you also might consider the [dev branch](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/develop), which includes some improvements in memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just seemed that this domPDF is using a lot of memory resourses, because when I tested to override php's memory limit with:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

it worked.

The view itself contained a lot of data, so that was the issue. I would NOT recommend overriding memory_limit like this. It was purely for testing purposes.